# Fill in columns based on information that is a comma separated column

Tags: r, split

I have a data set that is being updated every year. Now I have a new data and I have to fill in some columns based on a specific column
[image]

I need to match whatever information I have in 'Gender' column with its respective columns, so the end results it should look like this

[image]

I tried using split() but it didn't...
Thank you for all the help

Comment: is not the same, if you notice in the first picture, the entries are NA because i have to code them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use do this using `mutate` from `dplyr` package and `ifelse` .
Here is a little example:

```
`library(dplyr)
df <- data.frame(Year = c(2018, 2019), 
                 Gender = c(NA, "1,3"))

df %>% mutate(Gen_Fema = ifelse(is.na(Gender), NA , 
                                ifelse(grepl("1",Gender), "Yes", "No")), 
              Gen_Male = ifelse(is.na(Gender), NA , 
                                ifelse(grepl("2",Gender), "Yes", "No")), 
              Gen_Trans = ifelse(is.na(Gender), NA , 
                                 ifelse(grepl("3",Gender), "Yes", "No")), 
              Gen_other = ifelse(is.na(Gender), NA , 
                                 ifelse(grepl("4",Gender), "Yes", "No")))
```

Output:

```
  Year Gender Gen_Fema Gen_Male Gen_Trans Gen_other
1 2018   <NA>     <NA>     <NA>      <NA>      <NA>
2 2019    1,3      Yes       No       Yes        No
```